# ubinize erro in image file in linux

Tags: linux

i m trying to build an image file from source code every thing works ok but at the end i get the following msg and .img file is not created

ubinize: volume size was not specified in section "ubifs", assume minimum to fit image "tmp/ubifs.img"98660352 bytes (94.1 MiB)

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately questions like these are [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Oveflow, and therefore should be asked here:
[SuperUser](https://superuser.com) or here:  [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com)

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.